# Computing matrix trace $\mathrm{Tr}(A^2)$ if we know $BA+AB=X$ for known matrices $X$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a curious case where I want to compute the trace of a matrix $A^2$, which is technically defined as
\begin{align}
A=-\int_0^\infty e^{-tB}Xe^{-tB}dt\,,
\end{align}
where I know $X$ very well (analytical form), while for $B$ I only have an indirect form that it is given by $\sqrt{M(1-M)}$, where $M$ has an analytical form (with real, strictly positive eigenvalues).

I need to compute $\mathrm{Tr}(A^2)$. As I didn't have a better idea, I concluded that I can guess the integral of $f(t)=e^{-tB}Xe^{-tB}$ to be given by $F(t)=e^{-tB}Ye^{-tB}$, such that
\begin{align}
F'(t)=-e^{-tB}(YB+BY)e^{-tB}=f(t)=e^{-tB}Xe^{-tB}\,,
\end{align}
from which I conclude
\begin{align}
YB+BY=-X\,.
\end{align}
Evaluating the integral then yields $A=-F(0)=-Y$, so that I find that $AB+BA=X$.

**Now I wonder if there is any way to express $\mathrm{Tr}(A^2)$ in terms of the matrices $B$ and $X$...**